# Square integrable functions on the circle

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the Hilbert Space $L^2(S^1)$, the space of all square integrable functions on the unit circle. My question is whether all functions in this space can be written as a sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ for $a_n\in \mathbb{C}$.

I think this has something to do with Fourier Series, I seem to have forgotten such things. It would be very nice if someone indicated where can I read about this. Thank you.

Comment: Here one must be careful with the meaning of $f=\Sigma$ as this can mean that the series converges to $f$ pointwise, in $L^2$ norm or even in some other sense. Check relevant theorems on Wikipedia or somewhere. It is helpful if you specify what kind of convergence you need. Pointwise convergence at all points is notoriously not expected!

Comment: Here, by $z^n$, I mean the function from $S^1$ to $S^1$  that takes $t$ to $t^n$

Comment: These are the same as $e^{in\theta}$ -- which are mutually perpendicular (in the understood Hilbert space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the meaning of convergence, the answer is negative. The functions $\{z^n : n=0,1,2,\dots\}$ do not form a basis of $L^2(S^1)$ in any sense. Indeed, the function $\bar z$  (or $1/z$, which is the same thing on the circle) is orthogonal to all of them: 
$$
\int_{S^1} \bar z z^n = 0,\quad n=0,1,\dots
$$

But one can write $f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$, using both positive and negative powers of $z$.  Convergence holds

- in the sense of $L^2$ norm, that is $\left\| f - \sum_{|n|\le N} a_nz^n \right\|_2\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$;
- pointwise at almost every point of $S^1$ (Carleson's theorem)

The Wikipedia article [Convergence of Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series) is a good place to start.